# Rails: NoMethodError when trying to set up mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to set up a mailer. When a user submits a comment to a discussion I want the owner of that discussion to receive an email, but I keep getting a NoMethodError. I can't figure out where I'm supposed to define `email`... I'm hoping that's my only problem.

`undefined method 'email' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`

on this line here: `mail to: @user.email, subject: "You've got a comment!"`

comments_controller.rb create function:

```
  def create
    @discussion = Discussion.find(params[:discussion_id])
    @comment = @discussion.comments.build(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      Usermailer.commentcreated_email(@comment).deliver
      redirect_to new_discussion_comment_path(@discussion)
    end
  end
```

usermailer.rb

```
class Usermailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "***took out***"

  def commentcreated_email(comment)
    @comment    = comment
    @user       = @comment.users
    mail to: @user.email, subject: "You've got a comment!"
  end
end
```

development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :adress               => "smtp.gmail.com",         
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => "gmail.com",
    :user_name            => "***I do have an actual email here***",
    :password             => "***And an actual password***",
    :authentication       => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true }
```

commentcreated_email.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Comment Created</h1>
  <p>User <%= @comment.user %> posted a comment: </p>
  <br> <%= @comment.created_at.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p') %>
  <br> Project: <%= @comment.project.name %>
  <br> Hours: <%= @comment.hours %>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I didn't add anything in my user.rb but maybe I should have? This is what it looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :likes, dependent: :nullify
  has_many :liked_comments, through: :likes, source: :comment

  def has_liked?(comment)
    liked_comments.include? comment
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@user = @comment.users` which is returning you a `<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>` that is an array. So using email on the array will always throw an error. Change it the error will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I just changed it to .user but now i'm getting a strange error i've never seen before. `uninitialized constant ApplicationMailer` and it's highlighting `class Usermailer < ApplicationMailer` in my usermailer.rb?

Comment: @roguerat that may be, if you don't have `ApplicationMailer` that gets created the first time you run `rails g mailer MailerNameHere`.

Comment: @D-side hm, so I just went ahead and ran `rails g mailer usermailer` again, and since I already had it it skipped creating all of that. Except, apparently I didn't have an `application_mailer.rb` for some reason so it did create that. That fixed that error. But now i'm back to an undefined method error? `undefined method 'user' for #<Comment:0x007fa1d8f21710>`

Comment: @roguerat `Comment` `belongs_to :user` or not?

Comment: @D-side Ah that seemed to help! I fixed that and it changed the error a bit, now I'm back at my original error almost, it's just slightly different. `undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass` so I'm assuming this means email isn't defined anywhere?

Comment: @roguerat almost. `user` for the given `comment` is `nil`, that is, it doesn't exist.

Comment: @D-side what does that mean though? Do you see the problem? I don't understand... I just signed up with a new account, made a new project, then a new discussion for that new project, and then I went to comment on that discussion. That is when I get the `undefined method 'email' for nil:NilClass` error, whereas it should be sending an email to the owner of that discussion.

Comment: @roguerat that depends on whether you've done that right. The created comment seems to have `user_id` unset. I'm guessing `comment_params` doesn't return a hash, containing `user_id`, that hints that the form in a view is wrong.